# Find all integers i, j, k >= 0 such that i + j + k <= d?

Tags: c++, math

with `d` given as a parameters.

What is this problem called? Are these implementations of the solution to this problem in C++?

For example, if d = 2, then the solution would give :

```
2, 0, 0
0, 2, 0
0, 0, 2
1, 1, 0
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
0, 0, 1,
0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Stack overflow will not do your homework! Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, most importantly: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. "

Comment: Well, this is a subroutine of a larger problem which I am supposed to solve. I don't have to actually code a solution for this specific problem given in this question. I was just wondering if there's already some implementation in C++ that does it.

Comment: I don't think there is a name for this particular problem or any particular implementation of it, because it is trivial to solve optimally with three nested loops and the correct conditions on them and something like this has probably been written by everyone at some point.

Comment: As to what it's called: ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is helpful here; see particularly theorem two, and note that an equivalent problem is finding all 4-tuples `(i, j, k, l)` such that `i + j + k + l = d`.

Comment: But is it trivial to solve it in optimal time?

Comment: @truvaking The naive approach is the optimal one, if you actually need to enumerate all solutions.

Comment: care to elaborate what the naive approach is? just three nested loop, then check if the sum is <= d then add it to the list of enumeration?

Comment: @truvaking Basically, yes. The only optimization remaining is to notice that e.g. the inner loop for `k` will pass the `if` condition if and only if `k<=d-i-j`, so that can be used as loop condition instead. Something similar can be done for `j` and then you have the optimal solution.

Comment: sorry, why are we talking about optimal solution? we want every solution that satisfies the condition right?

Comment: @truvaking I am referring to the algorithm being optimal (sorry for the confusing wording), i.e. the algorithm is the one that takes the smallest amount of time to generate all the solutions of the ineqaulity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here follows some trivial code. It is optimal as it needs to generate each solution once.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= d; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; i+j <= d; ++j)
        for (int k = 0; i+j+k <= d; ++k)
            printf("%d + %d + %d <= %d\n", i, j, k, d);
```

You can easily add an extra condition `i <= j <= k` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= d; ++i)
    for (int j = i; i+j <= d; ++j)
        for (int k = i+j; i+j+k <= d; ++k)
            printf("%d + %d + %d <= %d\n", i, j, k, d);
```